# Load bootstrap and jquery libraries from angular-cli.json

Tags: jquery, angular, html, angular5

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "styles.css"
],
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
]
```

I have added the styles and scripts in `.angular-cli.json` Everything is working fine.

I'm using some `Jquery` related code in `index.html` and I'm facing the below exception

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
at (index):95
```

If I load the files using `.angular-cli.json` will it not reflect in my `index.html`?

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b75cdf)

I'm using animation.css and animation.js. Is it possible to load in `.angular-cli.json` file

```
AOS.init({
    easing: 'ease-in-out-sine',
    once:'true'
});
```

Comment: Can you provide an mvce?

Comment: try as follows,

declare var $: any;

Comment: @AntoAntony Where I need to declare?

Comment: @vicbyte mvce means?

Comment: if you want to use it in a component, then you should declare outside the component class

Comment: @Krishna https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @vicbyte I have added stackblitz URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add your jQuery script in `.angular-cli.json`, it'll be bundled and added just before the closing `body` tag, so probably just after your code. So when execution flow reaches your code, `$` is not defined yet.

What you can do it using the `windonw.onload` event to execute jQuery code after all js files have been loaded

```
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>

<script>

  window.onload = function(){
    $('#abc').html('hello');
    }
</script>
</html>
```

I did not manage to get this to work on stackblitz, probably because of the way they load scripts. But it does work on a normal project

**Note**: You should not use jQuery in angular projects if you don't absolutely need it. If you just require it for bootstrap, then have a look at the [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io) library, which offers a angular-native implementation of bootstrap

Comment: I'm using `ngx-bootstrap` library for components. JQuery is used for some animations.

Comment: Ok, I got confused because you are importing `node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js`

Comment: Thanks anyway!! I'm using AOS animation. Can I include that from node_modules. Can u pls check my edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your component.ts just declare as below

```
// Jquery declaration
declare var $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'abc',
  templateUrl: './abc.html',
  styleUrls: ['./abc.scss']
})
export class ABCComponent implements OnInit{
}
```

Comment: Sorry. Not in the component. I need it in `index.html`

Answer (score 0):

Install

```
npm i --save jquery
```

Declare

```
import {$,jQuery} from 'jquery';
window.$ = $;
window.jQuery = jQuery;
```

Comment: Where to add that